# PowerAutomate Flows: I need to create metabot

Tags: power-automate

anyone knows how to create flow for finding the difference of days and minutes in power automate

how to create flow for finding the difference of days and minutes in power automate

Answer (score 0):

```
div(sub(ticks(utcNow()),ticks(addDays(utcNow(),-1))),600000000)

div(sub(ticks(utcNow()),ticks(addDays(utcNow(),-1))),864000000000)

div(sub(ticks(utcNow()),ticks(addDays(utcNow(),-1))),36000000000)
```

Convert ticks into more readable unit
The result of the subtraction should be then converted into a more understandable number. You don’t want to show users the difference in billions. Use the div(…) expression to divide the number by a number representing the desired unit.

Divide by   To get

864000000000    days

36000000000 hours

600000000   minutes

10000000    seconds

https://tomriha.com/how-to-calculate-difference-between-two-times-in-power-automate/